# Magento 2 Configurable Product - Select Default Swatch

Tags: magento-2.2.1, configurable-swatches

So we have text swatches for an attribute that is set up on a series of configurable products. The attribute has a default selected but evidently selecting a default does nothing at all? I don't get the point.

I'd like to have the default swatch selected when a visitor hits the product page. At the very least I'd like to have the first swatch selected, I don't want nothing selected because it's confusing.

I had a fix for the swatch-renderer.js file in 2.1.4, but the fix no longer works in 2.2.1 I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Hi Did you found any solution for this ?